# Reduced mass and harmonic mean

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, orbital-motion

In two-body problems, a reduced mass has the form:

$\frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1+m_2}$,

which by appearance, is half of the harmonic mean of $m_1$ and $m_2$:

$\displaystyle\frac{2}{\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}}$

But is this just a result purely by mathematical deduction (and nothing more) that reduced mass has the same form as that of harmonic mean? Or is there any underlying reason/explanation for this?

Comment: An underlying reason/explanation for a mathematical claim - like any claim about harmonic averages - is ultimately mathematical. So the "mathematical deduction" and the "underlying reason" is really the same thing. Of course it's no coincidence that the reduced mass is proportional to the harmonic average.

Comment: where did the 2 come from?

Comment: @sav because it's the average of two reciprocals at the denominator position.

Comment: @LubošMotl thank you. Let me re-think it.

Comment: Harmonic mean is like adding resistors in parallel. Effectively you are adding conductance $1/R$ terms. With reduced mass you are adding mobility $1/m$ terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The harmonic mean involves averaging the reciprocals, so it is dominated by the *smaller* of the two values.  The reduced mass has the same requirement: The orbit of a small body around a large body is almost the same as the orbit of a small body about a fixed point.  This also "explains" the factor of 2: in the limiting case m1>>m2, the reduced mass = m2, not twice that.  By a happy "accident", the formula for the reduced mass is the simplest formula that meets these requirements.

Comment: I also have realized these features myself, but thought that there should be something more intuitive and straightforward. I might have got myself confused. As you and Lubos Motl said, these mathematical features of harmonic mean made itself appear in the formula of the reduced mass. It manifests the physical features of the system. That's all. Am I right?